# Cookie cannot be read by script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, cookies, flask

I'm trying to read a cookie from a browser by the following Javascript code using the `js-cookie` package. However, the cookie is not being read.

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
var cookie_name = 'cookie';
var cookie = Cookies.get(cookie_name);
console.log(cookie);
```

The cookie is created using the below Python code that utilizes `Flask`.

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, text/plain')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
response.set_cookie(key='cookie',
                value=payload,
                domain='<url>')
```

The Flask app has the following parameters

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = False
```

Above I've turned off the `HttpOnly` flag so my script should be able to read the cookie. I also cannot see the cookie using `console.log(document.cookie)` in the browser. Is there any reason why my JS code can't read the cookie?

Comment: `Cookies` is not a valid browser api. Cookies are always get/set via document.cookies.

Comment: @Geuis, Seems he using `react-cookie`

Comment: @Geuis I'm using the `js-cookie` library

Comment: how are you building the flask response?

Comment: Is the backend and frontend hosted on separate servers/domains?

Comment: can you show cookies from chrome debug panel?

Comment: If you can't see the cookie in the browser, you're question should be why the cookie is not being set. Your JS script might be fine but if the cookie is not there it cannot be read...

Answer (score 2):

If you can't see the cookie in the browser console it means that it either isn't being set or that it is being set with HTTP only.

`SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` should only affect the session cookie set by Flask, it looks like you are trying to set a different cookie entirely.

I would:

1. Confirm that the cookie is really being set (you can check this via dev tools)
2. If it is being set, and somehow being set with HTTP only turned on, change your code:

...

```
response.set_cookie(key='cookie', value=payload, domain=<url>, httponly=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should work with 'react-cookie', install it via npm. Then in your component try to import the HOC withCookies

```
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
```

get the cookies binding by key

```
    function getCookieFucnctionTest(myRecordFromCookies) {
       var value = "; " + document.cookie;
       var parts = value.split("; " + myRecordFromCookies+ "=");
       if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
     }
```

after the use of getCookieFucnctionTest and sotre it into a parametere

export your component with the HOC

```
export default withCookies(MyComponent);
```

Comment: I'd like to use the `js-cookie` library due to simplicity. Also, switching packages does not help as the cookie is not being detected on the browser. It's not clear why this cookie can't be read via a script as the Flask settings should allow it to be readable

Answer (score 0):

The fact you can't get to see your cookie through `console.log(document.cookies)` is possibly an indicator of a mismatch between the domain or path of your cookie and what the browser is trying to access.

EG: if your backend/Flask app is running on api.example.com:8080 and the client is using www.example.com:80 then you need to explicitly set the domain to `.example.com` to be readable globally on your domain, also you might incurr in a CORS error while setting the cookie on your AJAX request, you might need to add the following headers to Flask:

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Set-Cookie')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.example.com')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
response.set_cookie(key='cookie',
                value=payload,
                domain='.example.com')
```

You can also enforce a `path='/'` but it seems Flask does that by default, in any case you should be able to see your Cookies even with different paths but set on the same domain on your DevTools of choice under the screen `Application > Cookies` (in case the path is set incorrectly `console.log(document.cookies)` wont produce any result or might strip out the cookie you're after)